# Increasing/Decreasing Value of Multiple Cells in Selected Range VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spin button split into two events `SpinUp`&`SpinDown`. I want the user to select any given range of cells and then using the spin button, increase or decrease the value of the cells by 1. This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection

SpinButton1.Height = 45
SpinButton1.Width = 39
SpinButton1.Left = 283.5
SpinButton1.Top = 328.5

myRange.Value = myRange.Value + 1 
'(assume -1 for the SpinDown function)


End Sub
```

When I select more than one cell at a time, I get a Run-time error stating a type mismatch. I am very new to VBA/Excel programming so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to check if more than 1 cell is selected. Something like:

```
Sub test()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection

If myRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

MsgBox "Only 1 cell selected"
End Sub
```

Give this a try if you want to manipulate multiple cells:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Set myRange = Selection

SpinButton1.Height = 45
SpinButton1.Width = 39
SpinButton1.Left = 283.5
SpinButton1.Top = 328.5

    For Each myCell In myRange
        myCell.Value = myCell.Value + 1
    Next myCell

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Long time no see! Anyway, I'm actually trying to modify the value of more than one cell.

Comment: ah, ok. then you'll need to loop through each cell in that range.  hold on and I'll amend my code.

Comment: @DeeWBee edited code to loop through multiple cells.  let me know if that's what you're after.

Comment: Awesome it works! Quick question: what does the screen updating do exactly?

Comment: It keeps the screen from re-writing each time a cell is updated.  It makes the code a bit more responsive since the screen doesn't have to be repainted every time.  Since I wasn't sure if you'd be selecting 2 or 1,000,000 cells, I put it in there.  It doesn't hurt (and something you should get in the habit of doing if you have a lot of moving parts to your code)

Comment: I have this weird issue where the buttons on my screen will just keep getting bigger and bigger with every action (hence the hard-coding of the positions). Will the screen refresh fix or at least help with that issue?

Comment: No.  are the form or activex buttons?  You should probably open a new question for that since this one has been solved :)